# Multiplayer Game Resolution

Tags: coronasdk, game-engine, game-physics, screen-resolution

I have a problem with conception of multiplayer with different resolution 
ie. 320 x 480 and 960 x 640

And we have a multiplayer game where user can hit the ball with 5 round pawns. something like simple soccer game. 
And the question is: How to translate two different resolution and have the same game state on different screens ??

greetings

Comment: Your game state should be independent of the resolution on which it is played. For example, you could have the positions of entities stored as screen ratios instead in a 2D game. So, your x and y positions would be 0 - 1 relative to the screen. That way, you then just translate that ratio to any width or height of screen on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great article for you. It explains how Corona manages different size of screen.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html

Basically, screen size has the same dimensions as you define it in `config.lua`, no matter on which device are you running your app. BUT! If screen is too wide or too tall `display.screenOriginX` and `display.screenOriginY` store the "additional" size value. Also please take a look at it.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/screenOriginX.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont have an easy and reliable way of detecting what screen size users have. You simply define your resolution to target the most user:

```
application =
{
    content =
    {
        width = 320,
        height = 480,
        scale = "letterbox"
    },
}
```

Everyone will have the same numbers but the picture quality will increase with higher quality device screen